# How do I introduce an initialization constructor? C# CS0236

Tags: c#, constructor, access-modifiers

I'm getting multiple errors but I don't know why. The errors are introduced after the `GetArea` method.

```
namespace Lesson02
{
    class Rectangle
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

        }

        private double length;
        private double width;
        public Rectangle(double l, double w)

        {
            length = l;
            width = w;

        }

        public double GetArea()

        {
            return length * width;
        }

       public Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(10.0, 20.0);
       double area = rect.GetArea();
       Console.WriteLine("Area of Rectagle: {0}", area);
```

Comment: `Console.WriteLine("Area of Rectagle: {0}", area);` should be *within* a method

Comment: please write your complete class or a compilable part of it. And mention what exat error do you get.

Comment: I did write everything completely and I did include the error I got in the title of the question. Thank you for your answer but I am almost certain their have been times I have seen Console.WriteLine 'outside' of a method.

Answer (score 0):

You can't just put execution

```
Console.WriteLine("Area of Rectagle: {0}", area);
```

within the class scope as if it's *declaration*. Move it to the `Main` method:

```
namespace Lesson02
{
    class Rectangle
    {
        // Method, here we execute
        static void Main(string[] args)
        { 
            // Executions are within the method
            Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(10.0, 20.0);
            double area = rect.GetArea();
            Console.WriteLine("Area of Rectagle: {0}", area);
        }

        // Declarations
        private double length;
        private double width;

        public Rectangle(double l, double w)
        {
            length = l;
            width = w;
        }

        public double GetArea()
        {
            return length * width;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the assistance.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comment, you have class body mixed up with program code. It's also a bad idea to have everything in one class.

Your Rectangle class should be separate:

```
public class Rectangle
{
    private double length;
    private double width;

    public Rectangle(double l, double w)
    {
        length = l;
        width = w;

    }

    public double GetArea()
    {
        return length * width;
    }
}
```

And your program code separate:

```
public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(10.0, 20.0);
        double area = rect.GetArea();
        Console.WriteLine("Area of Rectagle: {0}", area);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Misza. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Either make class Rectangle as public otherwise change 
public Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(10.0, 20.0); as Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(10.0, 20.0);

```
    public class Rectangle
    {

        private double length;
        private double width;
        public Rectangle(double l, double w)
        {
            length = l;
            width = w;
        }

        public double GetArea()
        {
            return length * width;
        }

    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
         Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(10.0, 20.0);
        double area = rect.GetArea();
        Console.WriteLine("Area of Rectagle: {0}", area);
    }
```